# What would be the space of section of the bundle $\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \{e\}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \{e\}$a vector bundle over a point. What would be the sections of this bundle?

Comment: Sections are maps from the base to the top space that "descend" under $\pi$, i.e., each point is mapped to its fiber.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the sections are maps  from a point onto its fiber; the only maps from a point to its fiber are the constant maps $f(e)=g$ ; for g in $\mathfrak{g}$. But the bundle is trivial, since a single point is contractible ( or maybe "contracted" already), which makes sense, in that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g} \times ${$e$} .

Comment: Thanks, that was clarifying..

Comment: No problem, glad to help.